# How to implement math expression simplification using Active Pattern

Tags: f#, symbolic-math

The simplify function below tries to simplify a mathematical expression of type
`((2 + 3) * (2 + 4))`
to
`(2 * (3 + 4))`.

Ideally, I would like to write the match expression as:

```
| Product (Sum (c, a), Sum (c, b)) -> Product (c, Sum (a, b))
```

But that gives me the "c is bound twice in this pattern" error. So I resort to the guard condition.

I am wondering whether there is a better way to accomplish this using Active Patterns?

```
type Expr =
    | Number  of int
    | Sum     of Expr * Expr
    | Product of Expr * Expr

let rec eval =
    function
    | Number n       -> n
    | Sum (l, r)     -> eval l + eval r
    | Product (l, r) -> eval l * eval r

let rec show =
    function
    | Number n       -> n.ToString()
    | Sum (l, r)     -> "(" + show l + " + " + show r + ")"
    | Product (l, r) -> "(" + show l + " * " + show r + ")"

let rec simplify =
    function
    | Product (Sum (c, a), Sum (d, b)) when (c = d) -> Product (c, Sum (a, b))
    | Sum (l, r)     -> Sum (simplify l, simplify r)
    | Product (l, r) -> Product (simplify l, simplify r)
    | e -> e

let c = Product (Sum (Number 2, Number 3), Sum (Number 2, Number 4))
show c
eval c
show (simplify c)
```

Comment: The way you have it is correct, there is no shorter notation.

Comment: How are you "simplifying" `(2 + 3) * (2 + 4)` which equals `30` to `2 * (3 + 4)` which equals `14`?  These things are not equivalent.

Comment: ["Expert F# 4.0"](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/936182944) has a section on [Simplifying Algebraic Expressions](https://books.google.com/books?id=XKhPCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA339&lpg=PA339&dq=expert+F%23+4.0+Simplifying+Algebraic+Expressions.&source=bl&ots=GHXjjeHPbV&sig=I4wbdiF6WVWOx4EdES6KS4ohh7M&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwio54a0jKHSAhXC1CYKHQemCd4Q6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=expert%20F%23%204.0%20Simplifying%20Algebraic%20Expressions.&f=false) that might help.

Comment: You can download the source code for ["Expert F# 4.0"](http://www.apress.com/us/book/9781484207413)

Comment: @TheInnerLight - you are correct :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that active patterns are better, but they can be more declarative in the match statement, allowing you to break apart each case.

Here is a version using active patterns, I've also made fixes in the logic. Notice how it's more verbose:

```
type Expr =
    | Number  of int
    | Sum     of Expr * Expr
    | Product of Expr * Expr

let rec eval =
    function
    | Number n       -> n
    | Sum (l, r)     -> eval l + eval r
    | Product (l, r) -> eval l * eval r

let rec show =
    function
    | Number n       -> n.ToString()
    | Sum (l, r)     -> "(" + show l + " + " + show r + ")"
    | Product (l, r) -> "(" + show l + " * " + show r + ")"

let (|CommonFactor|_|) =
   function
    | Sum (Product (a, b), Product (c, d)) when (a = c) -> Some <| Product (a, Sum (b, d))
    | Sum (Product (a, b), Product (c, d)) when (a = d) -> Some <| Product (a, Sum (b, c))
    | Sum (Product (a, b), Product (c, d)) when (b = c) -> Some <| Product (b, Sum (a, d))
    | Sum (Product (a, b), Product (c, d)) when (b = d) -> Some <| Product (b, Sum (a, c))
    | _ -> None

let (|Operation|_|) simplify =
   function
    | Sum (l, r)     -> Some <| Sum (simplify l, simplify r)
    | Product (l, r) -> Some <| Product (simplify l, simplify r)
    | _ -> None

let (|Constant|_|) =
    function
    | Number _ as n -> Some n
    | _ -> None

let rec simplify =
    function
    | CommonFactor exp -> simplify exp
    | Operation simplify exp -> exp
    | Constant exp -> exp
    | _ -> failwith "Oh teh noes!"

let c = Sum (Product (Number 2, Number 3), Product (Number 2, Number 4))
show c |> Dump
eval c |> Dump
show (simplify c) |> Dump
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for. What is dump btw.

Comment: I was using LinqPad, so that basically prints it